# CSS @font-face not working?

Tags: html, css, font-face

In my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="add_ons/style_sheets/style.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">
        <p id ="text" >BALL</p>
    </div>

<body>
```

In the css I've tried:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Pier';
src: url('add_ons/sources/fonts/Pier.woff2') format('woff2');
src: url('add_ons/sources/fonts/Pier.woff') format('woff');
src: url('add_ons/sources/fonts/Pier.ttf') format('truetype');
}

#text{

    font-family: 'Pier';

}
```

And it did not work, I've also tried to remove the  `format('truetype')` part and to use `src: url('Path'), url('Path'), url('Path')` but that has not worked either.

Can somebody explain me how to properly insert my custom font into a webpage?

P.S.: My webpage isn't currently on any server I'm just opening the html file from my computer on chrome 47.0, could that be the cause?

Comment: Hi! The first thing to check is whether the fonts are being loaded properly and being referenced with the correct path. You can check that with the developers tools of your browser. Make sure there are no errors.

Comment: How should I do that? Could you explain?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your structure folder ?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practices is to always use a **relative** paths not absolute ones, to ensure it works for any domain.

From your code, I'm assuming you are having the following structure:

- Root

  - index.html
  - **add_ons**

    - **style_sheets**

      - style.css
    - **sources**

      - **fonts**

        - Pier.woff2
        - Pier.woff
        - Pier.ttf

You could simply update your paths in the CSS from:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Pier';
   src: url('add_ons/sources/fonts/Pier.woff2') format('woff2');
   src: url('add_ons/sources/fonts/Pier.woff') format('woff');
   src: url('add_ons/sources/fonts/Pier.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

To:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Pier';
   src: url('../sources/fonts/Pier.woff2') format('woff2');
   src: url('../sources/fonts/Pier.woff') format('woff');
   src: url('../sources/fonts/Pier.ttf') format('truetype');
 }
```

Comment: You are right.I was thinking of a position relative to the index.html and not to the stylesheet

Answer (score -1):

I found out the answer!

When you say url() css expects a full url and not a relative one.

So:I was using a Path relative to my index.html instead of a full complete path so `src: url('website/add_ons/sources/fonts/regular/Pier.woff2');`

You should use `src: url('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/website/add_ons/sources/fonts/regular/Pier.woff2');`

If you were using a website you should use the full path too ie`http://www.web.com/fonts/font.ttf`

Comment: Using absolute URLs to reference local assets is not a good practice.